# mapping an iframe as a texture - three.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, iframe, three.js

Is possible to dynamically map an iFrame as a texture, onto an obj model? I am aware you are able to do this with videos.

Combining this example - loading an iFrame into a three.js environment;
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html

With this example; which shows an image texture being mapped to an obj model.  http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

Are there any examples of this being implemented?

Comment: You might be able to do it by mapping it to a canvas then mapping then canvas to a WebGL. I am trying to explore this approach.

Comment: Phil's route is probably the easiest. Using a canvas as a texture works quite well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that with WebGL. Textures can only be taken from image or video elements. The demo you've referenced uses the browser's compositor to lay a CSS transformed IFrame over the WebGL canvas.